# I wonder how to return several objects (a Datatable as well as a stack) from a function?

Tags: c#

```
  public DataTable,Stack ReadTxtFile(string Flepath)
    {
        //some work done with datatable and stack
        Stack stk = new Stack();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        return dt,stk;
    }
```

I wonder the best way to return several objects from a single method?

Comment: If you're using C# 7 you can do value tuples with parenthesis `(DataTable, Stack)` and `return (dt, stk)`

Comment: You can use tuples - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples. Or, and I think that it's a better way, since you probably will need more data to return in the future - define return model or DTO - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object

Comment: Methods that return two seemingly-unrelated objects are a bad code smell. Can you explain in more detail what you're doing? This sounds like a method that needs redesigning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a `Tuple<Stack, Datatable>` return type.

Comment: still getting prob with return

Comment: @khashamkhan `return Tuple.Create(stack, table);` - however, a "value tuple" is easier to use (see my answer)

Answer (score 6):

There are various options here:

- use an `out` parameter for the extra info
- define your own type with multiple properties
- use a "value tuple" to represent the pieces (this requires recent C# versions)

As an example of the last:

```
public (DataTable table,Stack stack) ReadTxtFile(string Flepath)
{
    //some work done with datatable and stack
    Stack stk = new Stack();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    return (dt,stk);
}
```

with usage:

```
var (table,stack) = ReadTextFile(path);
```

However... as a side note: I would suggest "don't use `DataTable`" as a general guideline.

Answer (score 0):

Use output parameters, that's what they exist for:

```
public bool ReadTxtFile(string path, out Stack _stack, out DataTable _table)
{
    //some work done with datatable and stack
    _stack = new Stack();
    _table = new DataTable();
    return true; // Or false if you trapped an error or something...
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
Stack _stack = null;
DataTable _table = null;
var fileRead = ReadTxtFile(path, out _stack, out _table);
if (fileRead) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DTO:

```
public class ReadTxtFileResult
{
    public Stack Stack { get; set; }
    public DataTable DataTable { get; set; }
}
```

And return this instead:

```
public ReadTxtFileResult ReadTxtFile(string Flepath)
{
    Stack stk = new Stack();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    return new ReadTxtFileResult
    {
        Stack = stk,
        DataTable = dt
    }
}
```

Other ways are [`out` parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) or [tuples](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/). Imho a DTO is more clean and explicit.